# Email generator called from Application_NewMail is generating duplicate emails

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have this macro which picks the file (`pdf`) out of a specified folder and then emails it as an attachment.

It is running via Application_NewMail and then links to an Excel file where the pdf is created and saved.

It works but the attachment is sent twice in two separate emails - I thought about writing another macro to remove duplicate emails but I am afraid this might delete emails I do not want to delete.

Folder path and email address have been replaced by placeholders.

```
Sub Any_help_appreciated()

Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim fso As Object 'Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim strFile As String
Dim fsoFile 'As Scripting.File
Dim fsoFldr 'As Scripting.Folder
Dim dtNew As Date, sNew As String

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strFile = "FOLDER PATH" 'path to pdf folder

Set fsoFldr = fso.GetFolder(strFile)
dtNew = Now - TimeValue("00:00:30") 'select pdf if created in last 30 secs

For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files

    If fsoFile.DateCreated > dtNew Then

        sNew = fsoFile.Path

        Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With objMail
            .To = "email.address@email.com"
            .Subject = "Subject"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
            .Attachments.Add sNew
            .Send ' .send
        End With

    End If

Next fsoFile

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to add the attachments then send, so move your `objmail` creation etc to before the loop and  your `.send` out of the loop after next.  So all that is in the loop is the `.attachments.add`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thanks for the reply - same issue and it didn't like the fact that the .send wasn't with the rest of the email specs.

Comment: Is the newly created file open? while you running the code.

Comment: I do not get the logic of `select pdf if created in last 30 secs`.  Are you running this code periodically? That might have created that problem.

Comment: @0m3r no it is not, it has been saved and closed by then.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal it is running via Application_NewMail and then links to an excel file where the pdf is created and saved - the last 30 seconds allows me to pick up the most recent file (bit of a fudge I know). The whole process works fine, but I get two identical emails out at the end.

Comment: Can you show your `Application_NewMail` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two emails because `Application_NewMail` event handler gets executed twice and two emails are sent consecutively (only two because it takes some time before server processes the e-mail). I guess it is because `.To` value of `email.address@email.com` is your email account for testing.

Try to add some check if the code for `objMail.Send` does get executed twice like writing something to a text file, log etc.

Or move the PDF file to a different folder after processing it.

Comment: perfect thanks, as soon as i knew that was the reason I could work around that.